# Kibana kubernetes all containers dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, kibana

How to create dashboard which will show all running containers in a namespace along with how many different channel (header in route/rest api calls) calling the routes of that container?

Comment: It depends on what you are using, is anything sending data to your Kibana right now? We used metricbeat to get the data to Kibana and it has dashboards that should have the needed data. We used it for K8S and for EC2, both dashboards work great. A little guide here => [Link](https://itnext.io/config-kibana-dashboard-to-visualize-your-kubernetes-cluster-data-20a87bd7111d)

Answer (score 0):

Kibana is used for logging and Grafana for Monitoring. In order to create a dashboard that shows all running containers one could use Grafana.